# Different iframe for each day

Tags: java, html, css

I had a HTML with two iframes. How I force javascript to load **specific iframe with exact URL** for actual day?

```html
#div1
{
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 100px;
}

#iframe1
{
    top      : -500px;
    left     : -36px;
}
#div2
{
    width    : 315px;
    height   : 107px;
}
 
#iframe2
{
    top      : -500px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

<div id="div1">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL" id="iframe1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe2" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

The java index me on actual day position, I need replace Array with unique **iframe for each day.**

```
var d = new Date()
var weekday=new Array

("url1","url2","url3","url4","url5","url6","url7","url8","url9","url10","url11","url12","url13","url14","url15","url16","url17","url18","url19","url20","url21","url22","url23","url24","url25","url26","url27","url28","url29","url30","url31")
document.write(weekday[d.getDate()])
document.write("<br>");
document.write(weekday[d.getDate()-1])
```

Comment: Why you have taken 2 iframes while you have 31 URLs. You could also do this with a single iframe.

Comment: because its two iframe tables with different Pxs. sorry in my example i copy random numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use todays date using Date Function. We can calculate the day and try this day at array value of URL. I updated the code in Snippet.. I think this will be better to help you.

```js
var url = ["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5","url6","url7","url8","url9","url10","url11","url12","url13","url14","url15","url16","url17","url18","url19","url20","url21","url22","url23","url24","url25","url26","url27","url28","url29","url30","url31"];

var d = new Date();
   
   var loc= (d.getDate() < 10 ? " 0" : " ") + d.getDate() + " ";
 
    
    var ids = parseInt(loc);
    var srcURL = url[ids - 1];
    
      $('#iframe'+ids).attr("src", srcURL);
    $('#div'+ids).show();
```

```css
#div1
{
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 100px;
}

#iframe1
{
    top      : -500px;
    left     : -36px;
}
#div2
{
    width    : 315px;
    height   : 107px;
}
 .divs{
 display:none;
 }
#iframe2
{
    top      : -500px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div id="div1" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL" id="iframe1" scrolling="no">frame1</iframe>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe2" scrolling="no">frame2</iframe>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe3" scrolling="no">frame3</iframe>
</div>
<div id="div4" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe4" scrolling="no">frame4</iframe>
</div>
<div id="div5" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe5" scrolling="no">frame5</iframe>
</div>
<div id="div6" class="divs">
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe5" scrolling="no">frame6</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div24" class="divs">frame24
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe24" scrolling="no">frame24</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div25" class="divs">frame25
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe25" scrolling="no">frame25</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div26" class="divs">frame26
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe26" scrolling="no">frame26</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div27" class="divs">frame27
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe27" scrolling="no">frame27</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div28" class="divs">frame28
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe28" scrolling="no">frame28</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div29" class="divs">frame29
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe29" scrolling="no">frame29</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div30" class="divs">frame30
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe30" scrolling="no">frame30</iframe>
</div>

<div id="div31" class="divs">frame31
<iframe src="accurateDayURL-1" id="iframe31" scrolling="no">frame31</iframe>
</div>
```